# I retrieving the data from DB using JSP and I want to display that data list in using senchatouch2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

i have following jsp page.and it is displaying the result.

```
enter code here


<%@page language="java" import="java.sql.*, java.util.*, java.lang.*, net.sf.json.*,       org.json.simple.JSONObject" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"  %>



<%
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/thermo?user=root&password=");
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("select model_number from product");

JSONObject json      = new JSONObject();
JSONArray  addresses = new JSONArray();
//JSONObject address =new JSONObject();
    while(result.next())
    {
        //address.put(result.getString("model_number"));
        addresses.add(result.getString("model_number"));
    }
    json.put("Addresses", addresses);
    out.println(addresses);

response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
}
    catch (JSONException jse)
{ 

}
%>



 and i have following js file.

  I got the following Exception when i run the js file.
[WARN][Anonymous] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'Ext.dataview.List'; consider     adding 'Ext.dataview.List' explicitly as a require of the corresponding class
```

:8080/Sample/sdk/src/log/writer/Console.js?_dc=1334137320671:35

[WARN][Anonymous] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'; consider adding 'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP' explicitly as a require of the corresponding class

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ::8080/new/modelnumber_list.jsp?_dc=1334137328213&page=1&start=0&limit=25&callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback1:1

```
enter code here

 `Ext.define('Sample.view.Blog',{
       extend:'Ext.navigation.View',
       xtype:'bloglist',
       config:{
           title:'Blog',
           iconCls:'star',
           scrollable:true,
           styleHtmlContent: true,
           items:{
               xtype: 'list',
               itemTpl: '{model_number}',
               store:{
                   autoLoad: true,
                   fields: ['model_number'],
                   proxy:{
                       type: 'jsonp',
                       url: 'modelnumber_list.jsp',
                       reader:{
                           type: 'json',
                            rootProperty: 'root'
                       }
                   }
               }   
           }
       }
       });





Thank you.
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding this on the app.js not the view, this will remove the warning.

```
requires: ['Ext.data.Store', 'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP', 'Ext.dataview.List'],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line after `xtype:'bloglist',`. I think this will take care of the warnings you get.

```
requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'],
```

Comment: [WARN][Anonymous] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'Ext.dataview.List';
consider adding 'Ext.dataview.List' explicitly as a require of the corresponding class
Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Cannot create an instance of unrecognized alias: proxy.json
sencha-touch.js:6366

Comment: when i used the above code in my program i got the above error.